# Problems displaying .json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having trouble displaying two values on the screen( high-top and category):

This is my code:

```
      $.getJSON('data.json', function(obj){

        $.each(obj["best-seller"], function(key, value){

            console.log(value.title);    
            console.log(value.price); 
            console.log(value.higth-top); 
            console.log(value.category); 

                $("#produto").append(" <b>"
                    +value.title+"<br/>"
                    +value.price+"<br/>",
                    +value.category+ "<br/>",
                    +value.higth-top+ "<br/>",

                    "</b>"
                );
            });
    });
```

Note: Category is shown perfectly on the console, but in html it is **returned NaN**
And the higth-top is returned NaN in the console and also in the Html

Other values are normally displayed

I search the data in a .json, like this:

```
{
"best-sellers": [
  {
  "title": "Chuteira Nike HyperVenomX Proximo II Society",
  "price": 499.9,
  "installments": {
    "number": 10,
    "value": 49.9
  },
  "high-top": true,
  "category": "society",
  "image": "aaaa.jpg"
   }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: the reason is because it is trying to evaluate the expression , except category all others are nos, in addition to the `hyphen` in the attribute name that would cause an error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the commas inside the `append`.

Right now you've separated the variables by commas, giving `append` multiple arguments, and the plus signs acts as coercion to numbers instead of string concatenation, giving you `NaN` instead of the expected string

```
$("#produto").append(" <b>"  + value.title +
                     "<br/>" + value.price + 
                     "<br/>" + value.category + 
                     "<br/>" + value['higth-top'] + 
                     "<br/></b>"
);
```

Also note that hyphens aren't valid in dot-nation, as they also mean "subtract", you'd have to use bracket notation for the property `higth-top`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate a string with commas so you have to remove them, moreover hyphens are not allowed in dot-notation

```
 value.higth-top
```

here javascript understands "subtract `top` to `value.high`"

Write it as follows

```
$("#produto").append(" <b>"  + value.title +
                 "<br/>" + value.price + 
                 "<br/>" + value.category + 
                 "<br/>" + value['high-top'] + 
                 "<br/></b>"
);
```